# Hashes Are Not Matching

Tags: sql-server, hash, md5, sqldatatypes, hashbytes

I am hashing the same values, but am getting different results.

Here is a simplified example to explain what I am encountering:

I have a dimension table that looks like this:

| gender | gender_id |
| --- | --- |
| Male | 1 |
| Female | 0 |

The datatype for gender is NVARCHAR(6) and gender_id is INT

When I execute any of the following queries I get the same hash:

```
**Scenario 1:**
SELECT 
       CONVERT(BINARY(20), HASHBYTES('Md5', Concat(Gender, cast(gender_id as int))))
FROM demographic
WHERE gender = 'Male';
```

OUTPUT: '0x6B216D8BB993AA263265CCF645C282B100000000'

```
**Scenario 2:**
    SELECT  
           CONVERT(BINARY(20), HASHBYTES('Md5', Concat(Gender, CAST(gender_id AS NVARCHAR(1)))))
    FROM demographic
    WHERE gender = 'Male';
```

OUTPUT: '0x6B216D8BB993AA263265CCF645C282B100000000'

In scenario 1, I casted gender_id as an INT and in scenario 2 I casted gender_id as NVARCHAR. In both cases the hash was the same.

When I execute queries calling on the specific values in my dimension, instead of the columns, my hashes are different:

```
 **Scenario 3:**
    SELECT CONVERT(BINARY(20), HASHBYTES('MD5', Concat('Male', CAST(1 as INT))));
```

OUTPUT: '0x048A5F0EE2D2B4070CFF8A38CB6DAC7100000000'

```
**Scenario 4:**
    SELECT CONVERT(BINARY(20), HASHBYTES('MD5', Concat('Male', CAST(1 as NVARCHAR(1)))));
```

OUTPUT: '0x6B216D8BB993AA263265CCF645C282B100000000'

In scenario 3 I casted 1 as an INT just as I did in scenario 1. In scenario 4, I casted 1 as NVARCHAR just as I did in scenario 2. Yet, scenario 3 and 4 have different hashes. In addition to this the hash for scenario 4 is consistent with the hashes in scenarios 1 and 2.

I am having trouble understanding why the hashes are the same for scenario 1, 2, and 4, but different for scenario 3. In my dimension, gender_id is an INT. When I query my dimension, no matter how I cast it, the hash is always the same. In scenarios 3 and 4, when I replace the column names with the actual values the results change. The hash in scenario 3 will not match scenarios 1 and 2 unless I cast it as NVARCHAR. Why is this since gender_id is naturally an INT?

Would appreciate any insight you have, and would be happy to provide more clarification if needed.

Thanks!

Comment: why are you even concatenating gender_name and gender_id ?

Comment: I am just using that as a simplified example. In general though, I am using hashes for inserting or updating rows

Comment: Perhaps you have an XY problem?

Comment: Yeah he really good question. I had a similar problem. It was trying to hash a "french bull dog"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**`'Male'` is an ANSI `varchar` value, not a Unicode `nvarchar`. For Unicode you need `N'Male'`**

So for example, I get the following result for this query:

```
select convert(varchar(20), cast('Male' as varbinary(20)), 1)
```

**0x4D616C65**

Whereas this one, note the addition of `N` before the literal:

```
select convert(varchar(20), cast(N'Male' as varbinary(20)), 1)
```

**0x4D0061006C006500**